# Javascript: Any better solution to create table using user Input?

Tags: javascript

Here I'm trying to build a table based on user Input. But my code is not working. Don't understand what's the main problem is!. I've been searching for hours, and I can't find the answer that I've been looking for.  It will be great for me if anyone help! 
Thank You

> Here is my Html Code..

```
<h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit" id="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas">
        <tbody id="tbody">

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

> Here is my Js code

```
const height = document.querySelector("#inputHeight").value;
const width  = document.querySelector("#inputWidth").value;
const table = document.querySelector("#pixelCanvas");
const tBody = document.querySelector("#tbody");
const color = document.querySelector("#colorPicker").value;
const form = document.querySelector("#sizePicker");


// Event Listener
form.addEventListener('submit', makeGrid);





// makeGrid function

function makeGrid(event) {

    // Preventing from reloading
     event.preventDefault();




    // For Loop for rows

    for(var i=1; i<height;i++){


        const row = document.createElement("tr");

// For Loop for column

        for(var i=1; i<width; i++){
            const cell = document.createElement("td");
            row.appendChild(cell);


        }
        tBody.appendChild(row);
    }


}
```

Comment: I haven't looked through everything, but this and similar lines where you get the value: `const height = document.querySelector("#inputHeight").value;` need to be inside the `makeGrid` function, otherwise they'll always be the default initial value, not the value the user submitted in the form.

Comment: @RobinZigmond later I inserted it to makeGrid function. But there is one more problem I face. I actually can't make the table using given value. If I input height= 6 there should be 6 rows but it shows me a single column! 
What should I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method

**Note:** `height` and `width` is assigned to elements not value. So that we can get the value later even if it is changed.

```js
const height = document.querySelector("#inputHeight");
const width = document.querySelector("#inputWidth");
const table = document.querySelector("#pixelCanvas");
const tBody = document.querySelector("#tbody");
const color = document.querySelector("#colorPicker");
const form = document.querySelector("#sizePicker");


// Event Listener
form.addEventListener('submit', makeGrid);

// makeGrid function
function makeGrid(event) {
  // Preventing from reloading
  event.preventDefault();

  let cells = "<td></td>".repeat(width.value);
  let rows = `<tr>${cells}</tr>`.repeat(height.value);

  tBody.innerHTML = rows;
}
```

```css
#tbody td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

<h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
<form id="sizePicker">
  Grid Height:
  <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="2"> Grid Width:
  <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="2">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<h2>Pick A Color</h2>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker">

<h2>Design Canvas</h2>
<table id="pixelCanvas">
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting these two

`const height = document.querySelector("#inputHeight").value;
 const width  = document.querySelector("#inputWidth").value;`

before the function is executed. So t will never get updated input. Secondly , the `td` are empty , that is why you are not able to view it. Adding the `index` as `td` text

```js
const table = document.querySelector("#pixelCanvas");
const tBody = document.querySelector("#tbody");
const color = document.querySelector("#colorPicker").value;
const form = document.querySelector("#sizePicker");

form.addEventListener('submit', makeGrid);

function makeGrid(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const height = document.querySelector("#inputHeight").value;
  const width = document.querySelector("#inputWidth").value;
  for (var i = 1; i < height; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var i = 1; i < width; i++) {
      let k = document.createTextNode(i);
      const cell = document.createElement("td");
      cell.appendChild(k)
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    tBody.appendChild(row);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

<h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
<form id="sizePicker">
  Grid Height:
  <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
  <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<h2>Pick A Color</h2>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker">

<h2>Design Canvas</h2>
<table id="pixelCanvas" border='1px solid black'>
  <tbody id="tbody">

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: thank's Brother. But there is one more problem whenever I input height = 8
 and width = 6 there should be 8 rows and 6 columns. But i get a single row with 6 
 columns. How can I solve this?